# Create Nested If and else Define C Programming

Tags: c, bit

i need some help.
i want to create a #define for an bit operation. Additional, to the bit operation itself i want to check the sizes to be sure that i am performing a bit operation with the same data type size.

So what i tried is this here:

```
#define bitset(byte,nbit)  (sizeof(nbit) <= 2 ? (sizeof(nbit) == 2 ?  ((byte) |=  ((uint16)1<<(nbit))) : ( (byte) |=  ((uint8)1<<(nbit)))) \
                                      : (sizeof(nbit) == 8  ?  ((byte) |=  ((uint64)1<<(nbit))) : ( (byte) |=  ((uint32)1<<(nbit)))\
```

Did i made sth. wrong ? Is it even possible to create such a define ?

Comment: `sizeof(nbit) == 4 ?  ((byte) |=  ((uint64)1<<(nbit)))` shouldn't it be `sizeof(nbit) == 8`?

Comment: Put a '\' at the end of each line of a multiline define statement.

Comment: ah true i will try it thanks

Comment: Why a macro for this ?

Comment: Also why do you `sizeof(nbit)` and not `sizeof(byte)`??

Comment: @Orel Because of run time issues i want to avoid function

Comment: Could you please elaborate, in plain english, on what bit operation are you trying to perform and what "run time issues" are you trying to avoid?

Comment: what are you trying to "check" with these tests?  You could just do `(byte) |= (uint64_t)1 << (nbit))` to work for any size up to 64 bits.  This will fail if `nbit` is out of range for the type of `byte`, but that's the same as your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this define correct ?

No, you made some mistakes.

Firstly, I believe you want to check `sizeof(byte)` not the size of the variable that represents the bit number...

It should be `== 8 ? ((byte) |=  ((uint64)1<<(nbit))`, so that `uint64_t` is picked when `byte` has `8` bytes.

You missed a `\` on the end of define to join it with the next line.

You missed two `))` on the end to close the open ones.

There are no `uint8` and no `uint64` etc. There are types `uint16_t` and `uint8_t` etc. from `stdint.h`. Use standard types.

But consider however a clearer formatting:

```
#define bitset(byte,nbit)  ( \
      sizeof(byte) == 1 ? ((byte) |= (uint8_t)1<<(nbit)) : \
      sizeof(byte) == 2 ? ((byte) |= (uint16_t)1<<(nbit)) : \
      sizeof(byte) == 4 ? ((byte) |= (uint32_t)1<<(nbit)) : \
      ((byte) |=  (uint64_t)1<<(nbit)) \
)
```

> Is it even possible to create such a define ?

Sure it is. If you do not care about the return value and the expression doesn't have to be a constant expression, then you could even write full statements with the old `do { ... } while(0)` trick (or convention actually):

```
#define bitset(byte,nbit)  do { \
    static_assert(sizeof(byte) == 1 || \
            sizeof(byte) == 2 || \
            sizeof(byte) == 4 || \
            sizeof(byte) == 8, \
            "nbit has wrong size"); \
    assert(nbit < sizeof(byte) * CHAR_BIT); /* right? */ \
    switch (sizeof(byte)) { \
        case 1: (byte) |=  (uint8_t)1<<(nbit); break; \
        case 2: (byte) |=  (uint16_t)1<<(nbit); break; \
        case 4: (byte) |=  (uint32_t)1<<(nbit); break; \
        case 8: (byte) |=  (uint64_t)1<<(nbit); break; \
    } \
} while(0)
```

or similar. You may also explore `_Generic` and make your code accept explicitly only these types that you want to:

```
void bitset_8(uint8_t *byte, unsigned nbit) {
    *byte |= (uint8_t)1<<nbit;
}
void bitset_16(uint16_t *byte, unsigned nbit) {
    *byte |= (uint16_t)1<<nbit;
}
void bitset_32(uint32_t *byte, unsigned nbit) {
    *byte |= (uint32_t)1<<nbit;
}
void bitset_64(uint64_t *byte, unsigned nbit) {
    *byte |= (uint64_t)1<<nbit;
}
#define bitset(byte,nbit)  (_Generic((byte), \
    uint8_t: bitset_8, \
    uint16_t: bitset_16, \
    uint32_t: bitset_32, \
    uint64_t: bitset_64)(&byte, nbit))
```

All in all, this function is just an example. In real code I would anyway write:

```
#define bitset(byte,nbit)   ((byte) |= 1ull<<(nbyte))
```

as I trust the compiler will be smart enough to inline the expression and compiler will optimize, that if `byte` has for example 8 bits, then there's no need to use full 64-bit arithmetic and it will use 8 bytes.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for this comprehensive answer. It helped a lot.

Comment: i tried to implement the switch case you propose but somehow it always enter case 1. Even if byte is a long. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: [works fine here](https://godbolt.org/z/WrEjWK). `uint8_t` is going to be implicitly casted to `int` anyway.